# How to fix AWS EMR Spark and Zeppelin version mismatch?

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

AWS EMR 5.0 ships with `Spark: Spark 2.0.0 on Hadoop 2.7.2 YARN with Ganglia 3.7.2 and Zeppelin 0.6.1` prepackaged, but Zeppelin 0.6.1 only support Spark 1.6.x. Is there a way to address the version discrepancy without building and deploying a custom version of Zeppelin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Zeppelin 0.6.1 was the first version that does work with Spark 2.0.0.

Comment: Note that the zeppelin 0.6.1-SNAPSHOT shipped with EMR 5.0.0 is buggy and only partially supports spark 2.0.  In particular, UDFs do not work.  That's fixed in Zeppelin 0.6.2

Answer (score 1):

the customized version of Zeppelin on emr-5.0.0 works with Spark 2.0.

Comment: same here. I have no problem running Zeppelin with spark 2.0 on EMR 5.0 (both pyspark and spark)

Comment: Note: the version of Zeppelin on emr-5.0.0 is 0.6.1-SNAPSHOT because 0.6.1 was not fully released by the time emr-5.0.0 was about to be released. However, the 0.6.1-SNAPSHOT version that was released with emr-5.0.0 is not far off from what was eventually released as 0.6.1, and it does support Spark 2.0.

Comment: Also, the official version of Zeppelin 0.6.1 was released in emr-4.8.0 (some time after emr-5.0.0 came out), and Zeppelin 0.6.1 it will be on the next version of emr-5.x when it comes out.

Comment: The version of zeppelin shipped with EMR 5.0.0 (0.6.1-SNAPSHOT) does not support UDFs with spark 2.0.  This is a known Zeppelin bug that's fixed in Zeppelin 0.6.2.